# Balancing BST with inorder traversal (no rotations)

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I need to balance a normal BST using the inorder traversal output. The idea is quite simple: Look for the mean of the list and do the same thing recursively for all sidelists. This adds nodes each level at a time and should theoretically result in a new, balanced tree. However, I can't seem to get the code quite right. Can anyone give me a hint on where I am going wrong?

```
public void simpleBalance() {
    if (this.isEmpty()){
        return;
    }

    balancedTree = new Tree();

    balanceHelper((this.size() - 1) / 2);
    balanceHelper(this.size() - 1);

    this.root = balancedTree.root;
}

public void balanceHelper(int k){
    if (balancedTree.size() == this.size()){
        return;
    }

    if((k/2) >= this.size()){
        return;
    }

    if (k == 1){
        balancedTree.insert(valueAtPosition(0));
    }
    balancedTree.insert(valueAtPosition((k/2)));

    balanceHelper((k - 1) * 2);
    balanceHelper((k + 1) * 2);

}
```

Complete Code:

http://pastebin.com/tbUaYgFh

```
Output:
Height old tree:
9
Root old tree:
1
Old traversal:
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,

New traversal
3,4,5,6,8,9,10,
Height new tree:
5
Root new tree:
3
```

Comment: Could you please paste whole code with an example of actual result and the expected one?

Comment: Thank you, could you also post the expected result? I don't want to remind myself the theory for that :)

Comment: What I want is a tree with a maximum height difference of 1 between the leaves. The idea is: Inorder gives me an ordered list:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10  
  
If the root is 3 for example the tree is not balanced. If I were to take this list and use the mean (5) as the new root and do the same for each sublist that emerges (i.e. 1 2 (3) 4 and 6 7 (8) 9 10) I get a perfectly balanced tree.  
  
One thing: The inordered list starts with a 0 index